# how to create a hierarchical datastructure just like xml using .net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

i want to crate a hierarchical data structure same as XML, means parent, child, sub child... like that one using vb.net. so ho can i create that one?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`XElement` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) to model an XML tree.

Comment: i don't have to use XML, but by functionality wise i want to create it exactly like XML.

Comment: Then you might as well use XML, at least in-memory.  You can easily use XElement to hold an in-memory tree without actually generating XML.

Comment: No point in reinventing the wheel when you're trying to make the exact same wheel

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general pattern for creating parent-child relationships.

```
Public Class Node

  Private m_Children As List(Of Node) = New List(Of Node)

  Public ReadOnly Property Children() As List(Of Node)
    Get
      Return m_Children
    End Get
  End Property  

End Class
```